# HTML and Javascript with two buttons and a display panel that shows “0” at the start of the program,

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me with this- one of the buttons increments the number in the display panel and the other decrements it. The number in the display can go below zero if the decrement button is clicked enough times?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Can you Post a snippet or something. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Are You Looking For This Kind Of Functionality:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>+-</title>
    <script>
        let value = 0;
        function setInitial(){
            document.getElementById('value_display').innerHTML = "Value :- "+value;
        }
        function increment(){
            value++;
            document.getElementById('value_display').innerHTML = "Value :- "+value;
        }
        function decrement(){
            value--;
            document.getElementById('value_display').innerHTML = "Value :- "+value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setInitial()">
    <p id="value_display">Value :- </p>
    <button onclick="increment()">+</button>
    <button style="margin-left: 10px;" onclick="decrement()">-</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="results">Results 0</h1>
    <button id="inc">increment</button>
    <button id="dec">decrement</button>
    <script>
        let number = 0;
        const increment = document
          .getElementById("inc")
          .addEventListener("click",() => {
              (number += 1);
              document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Results "+number;
          });
        const decrement = document
          .getElementById("dec")
          .addEventListener("click",() =>{
               (number -= 1);
               document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Results "+number;
              });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what you need right?

In addition to that, you got two minus marks for your question.
Why?
Because you didn't show that any code to prove that you tried to do something. People in StackOverflow will only help you if you try first and then ask for the help. It's okay this is your first time and you didn't know these things. But next time onwards show what you did first before yu asking the help.